# Removing subqueries to improve performance

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

I have big query which is returning around 10,000 rows and takes around 15-20 seconds for execution. This is a legacy query and we want to improve the performance. We're using 4-5 inner join and subqueries.

I've seen in execution plan that subqueries/ Or condition is creating lazy spool and I would like to remove it.

Can you please tell me how can we remove the extra conditions and improve the query performance.

```
SELECT
        mc.OTCCustomerID,
        'L' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR, MC.custlevel) AS Custlevel,
        @CustomerNbr,
        @ParentNumber,
        OTC1.ParentNumber AS GParent,
        OINV.DisputeCnt,
        OINV.Matter,
        OINV.MatterDesc,
        OINV.MatterTrust,
        OINV.TransactionNbr,
        OINV.TransactionDt,
        OINV.TransactionDueDt,
        OINV.NextActionDt,
        OINV.InvoiceStatusId,
        OINV.RemainingBalance,
        OINV.TransactionCurrencyCd,
        OINV.RemainingTransactionBalance,
        OINV.Days,
        OINV.BillingTmkNm,
        OINV.SupervisingTmk,
        OINV.ClientPartnerNm,
        LEFT(MC.customernm,20)    AS CustomerNm,
        OINV.IsTransactionReopen,
        OINV.IsBPTPCode,
        CD.PrimaryDecodeTxt AS outcome,
        OINV.TransactionType,
        OINV.CollectorComments,
        ISNULL(OINV.OTCInvoiceDetailsID,0) AS OTCInvoiceDetailsID,
        OINV.BalanceDue,
        OINV.Amount,
        OINV.CheckNbr,
        OINV.ExpectedDepositDt

FROM    dbo.OTCCustomer MC WITH( NOLOCK)
JOIN    dbo.OTCInvoiceDetails OINV WITH( NOLOCK)    
    ON  MC.OTCCUSTOMERID            = OINV.OTCCUSTOMERID
JOIN    dbo.CODEDETAIL CD WITH( NOLOCK)    
    ON  OINV.CollectionEffortOutComeID= CD.ID
JOIN    dbo.PrioritizationTypeFilter  PTF WITH( NOLOCK)    
    ON  OINV.TransactionType        = PTF.FilterName
JOIN    OTCCollectionStrategyFilter   CSF WITH( NOLOCK)
    ON  PTF.PrioritizationFilterID  = CSF.PrioritizationFilterID 
    AND CSF.CollectionStrategyId    = @strategyID
JOIN    dbo.OTCCustomer OTC1    
    ON  MC.ParentNumber             = OTC1.CustomerNbr 
    AND OINV.InvoiceStatusId        = 5 
    AND OINV.CSExecSource IS NOT NULL 
    AND (((SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),OINV.NextActionDt)) <= 0) 
      OR
        ((OINV.CollectionEffortOutComeID IN (
            SELECT id
            FROM  dbo.codedetail WITH( NOLOCK)
            WHERE IsPTPEnabled = 1)) 
        AND (SELECT  DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),OINV.ExpectedDepositDt)) <= 0) 
      OR
        (OINV.CollectionEffortOutComeID IN (
            SELECT id
            FROM   dbo.codedetail WITH( NOLOCK)
            WHERE  IsBPTPEnabled = 1))) 
    AND
       OINV.CollectionEffortOutComeID NOT IN (
            SELECT id
            FROM   dbo.codedetail WITH( NOLOCK)
            WHERE  PrimaryDecodeTxt = 'DL01-Dunning Letter 1' 
                OR PrimaryDecodeTxt = 'DL02-Dunning Letter 2' 
                OR PrimaryDecodeTxt = 'DL03-Dunning Letter 3')
```

Comment: Yes, Indexes are there for columns being used in Select statement

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can simplify is that you don't to write your DATEDIFF statements as "SELECT ....", you can just say:

```
AND DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), OINV.NextActionDt) <= 0
```

or even simpler:

```
AND OINV.NextActionDt < GETDATE()
```

secondly, depending on how big the CodeDetail table is you may want to query it before you do everything else.  Something like:

```
;
WITH CodeDetailFoo AS (
 SELECT id, IsPTPEnabled, IsBPTPEnabled
 FROM    dbo.codedetail WITH ( NOLOCK )
 WHERE IsPTPEnabled = 1 OR IsBPTPEnabled = 1
)
<<PUT THE REST OF YOUR QUERY HERE and use CodeDetailFoo>>
```

The "WITH" approach means that the table gets queried once up front instead of for each row.

Comment: CodeDetail contains 40 rows and is a reference table and not a transaction table.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be more faster, I don't have means to check for syntax, please check in to that

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
            mc.OTCCustomerID,
            'L' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR, MC.custlevel) AS Custlevel,
            @CustomerNbr,
            @ParentNumber,
            OTC1.ParentNumber AS GParent,
            OINV.DisputeCnt,
            OINV.Matter,
            OINV.MatterDesc,
            OINV.MatterTrust,
            OINV.TransactionNbr,
            OINV.TransactionDt,
            OINV.TransactionDueDt,
            OINV.NextActionDt,
            OINV.InvoiceStatusId,
            OINV.RemainingBalance,
            OINV.TransactionCurrencyCd,
            OINV.RemainingTransactionBalance,
            OINV.Days,
            OINV.BillingTmkNm,
            OINV.SupervisingTmk,
            OINV.ClientPartnerNm,
            LEFT(MC.customernm,20)    AS CustomerNm,
            OINV.IsTransactionReopen,
            OINV.IsBPTPCode,
            CD.PrimaryDecodeTxt AS outcome,
            OINV.TransactionType,
            OINV.CollectorComments,
            ISNULL(OINV.OTCInvoiceDetailsID,0) AS OTCInvoiceDetailsID,
            OINV.BalanceDue,
            OINV.Amount,
            OINV.CheckNbr,
            OINV.ExpectedDepositDt,
            CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),OINV.NextActionDt) <= 0 THEN 1 
                WHEN  (UDF_TBL.MY_IND = 2 AND OINV.CollectionEffortOutComeID = UDF_TBL.ID AND DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),OINV.ExpectedDepositDt) <= 0) THEN 1
                WHEN (UDF_TBL.MY_IND = 1 AND OINV.CollectionEffortOutComeID = UDF_TBL.ID) THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END AS FILTER_IND

    FROM    dbo.OTCCustomer MC WITH( NOLOCK)
    JOIN    dbo.OTCInvoiceDetails OINV WITH( NOLOCK)    
        ON  MC.OTCCUSTOMERID            = OINV.OTCCUSTOMERID
    JOIN    dbo.CODEDETAIL CD WITH( NOLOCK)    
        ON  OINV.CollectionEffortOutComeID= CD.ID
    JOIN    dbo.PrioritizationTypeFilter  PTF WITH( NOLOCK)    
        ON  OINV.TransactionType        = PTF.FilterName
    JOIN    OTCCollectionStrategyFilter   CSF WITH( NOLOCK)
        ON  PTF.PrioritizationFilterID  = CSF.PrioritizationFilterID 
        AND CSF.CollectionStrategyId    = @strategyID
    JOIN    dbo.OTCCustomer OTC1    
        ON  MC.ParentNumber             = OTC1.CustomerNbr 
        AND OINV.InvoiceStatusId        = 5 
        AND OINV.CSExecSource IS NOT NULL
      AND OINV.CollectionEffortOutComeID NOT IN (
                SELECT id
                FROM   dbo.codedetail WITH( NOLOCK)
                WHERE  PrimaryDecodeTxt = 'DL01-Dunning Letter 1' 
                    OR PrimaryDecodeTxt = 'DL02-Dunning Letter 2' 
                    OR PrimaryDecodeTxt = 'DL03-Dunning Letter 3')  
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT id, CASE WHEN IsBPTPEnabled = 1 THEN 1 WHEN IsPTPEnabled = 1 THEN 2 END AS MY_IND
            FROM  dbo.codedetail WITH( NOLOCK)
            WHERE IsPTPEnabled = 1 OR IsBPTPEnabled = 1
        ) AS UDF_TBL
      ON       OINV.CollectionEffortOutComeID = UDF_TBL.ID
 ) A 
WHERE FILTER_IND = 1
```

Comment: What does "A" near last where condition specifies?

Comment: That's an Alias for the query used within FROM clause. It is not a condition :)

Comment: I ran your query in the database and it is taking 12-13 seconds to return the data of 42K rows. The query that I've posted is taking 5-6 seconds, not sure what happened :(